# USB 2.0 not working on Ubuntu, but working fine in GRUB

Tags: usb, xhci-hcd

Devices connected using the motherboard's USB 2.0 won't work in Ubuntu 14.04, although they work fine in GRUB 2.

`dmesg` spits out something along those lines when I connect a keyboard:

```
usb 7-3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ohci-pci
usb 7-3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 7-3: device not accepting address 6, error -32
usb 7-3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ohci-pci
usb 7-3: device not accepting address 7, error -32
usb 7-3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ohci-pci
usb 7-3: device not accepting address 8, error -32
usb 7-3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ohci-pci
usb 7-3: device descriptor read/8, error -32
usb 7-3: device descriptor read/all, error -32
usb usb7-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Connecting the same keyboard to the motherboard's USB 3.0 works fine.

Comment: Thanks. If this is an USB driver issue please post the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A 2 -Fe USB` and the entries of `sudo dmesg | grep -iFe usb` of the first 2 minutes since boot.

Comment: Since the keyboard only uses USB 1.1, can you check, if this is a bug in the `ehci_hcd` module? See http://www.geekdevs.com/2010/04/solved-unable-to-enumerate-usb-device-disabling-ehci_hcd/

Answer (score 3):

I needed to enable the [input/output memory management unit (IOMMU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOMMU) in the BIOS.